# Change div id on page1 if page2 contain element

Tags: javascript

I need to change one string on page1 (mysite.com/page1.html) if page2 (mysite.com/page2.html) contain specified div.

```
if (document.getElementById("div_id")) {
var str = document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML;
var n = str.replace("Login", "Logout");
document.getElementById("div_id").innerHTML = n;
}
```

This works only on same page but how to get element from another page ? I rather not use iframe.

Comment: what is the need for u

Comment: I need to change 'Log in' in 'Log out' on page1 if memebers are logged on page2. If they login on page2 new div shows up.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use some server-side scripting language instead of using plain html. When there are such logic dependencies between different pages, it means that you need to use something more than just static pages. It is possible to do it without server-side scripting by using JS/Ajax, but it's not the usual way of doing that.

Answer (score 0):

Try opening the 2nd page in an iframe of size 1x1 pixels from inside page #1.  When the `onload` event for the iframe is triggered the page finished loading and then you can get the document in the iframe and check to see the specified div is there or not.

edit:
I completely agree with @aram90, and think that this is a very bad way of programming websites. You should reconsider your options, most likely there is a much better alternative.

Comment: What will be the impact ? I'm a newbie, I hardly get help with my issues, right now one question = -4 . How'm I going to make it right if I stick 2-4 days for one small issue like this one..

Comment: Mainly the impact is that it will take you 10 times more time to develop simple tasks this way, it will have user impact (slower loading) and it will break in dozen different way when you make small changes. What backend technology are you using?  PHP? Rails? Django?  I suggest you ask a new question asking about making a log-in/log-out button with the relevant backend tech.

Answer (score 0):

try to put some variable in session .Depending on the value of that you can hide /show the div.